# How to prevent a Presta valve core from unscrewing when disconnecting a pump

Tags: pump, tubeless, valves, presta

My mini-pump has a screw-on head (as I guess most of them do) and several times when removing the pump from the valve, it's taken the valve core out with it.

The last time this happened to me on the road, I tried screwing the core in tighter and it simply sheered in half, leaving me with broken valve core stuck in the valve shaft. There seems to be a fairly narrow range where the core is tight enough to stay in place, and not so tight that it breaks.

Are there any reliable ways to prevent this, or any adapters or attachments for mini-pumps that do not screw onto the valve core? I am using tubeless tyres, so I can't use a valve without an integrated core.

Comment: Your question is for tubeless, but when using tubes I just moved to non-removable valves on the bike that I use with a screw-on adapter. I also often had the core unscrewed before that.

Comment: fwiw If you're not a fan of threaded connectors like myself, then it's actually fairly easy to find quality mini-pumps that don't use threaded connector. The ones I use come from Topeak and most of their range do not use threaded connectors https://www.topeak.com/global/en/products/216-Mini-Pumps. Last time I looked most of the major brands e.g. Birzman, SKS, Syncros, Specialized, Beto etc also  have many non-threaded options.

Comment: @shufflingb Over time, the seal of a non-threaded pump for a presta valve will wear out and get torn up as it's dragged across the threads of the valve both when the pump head is pushed onto the valve stem and then again when the pump head is removed.  Finding out your minipump will no longer seal to the valve stem when you get a flat 50+ km from home is not good.

Comment: I've mostly used Continental and Schwalbe tubes. I have found that Schwalbe tubes are great at retaining the valve core and I never had issue with it unscrewing when attaching/detaching a pump head. However it's a different story with Continental Race 28 tubes, every 4-5 times or so, I will need to tighten the presta valve core. FYI: I'm using a Xiaomi electric inflator that requires you to screw onto the valve before pumping air.

Comment: Hi @AndrewHenle, Yes, the seals do wear, but then so do the seals in threaded connectors. Only reliable way to avoid pump problems is to check them with tyres pressures before each ride. fwiw, should also regulary check any spare inner tube(s) and patch kits. Pump and tube strandings definitely soul crushing events that are best avoided.

Comment: @shufflingb *so do the seals in threaded connectors.* True, but threaded connectors don't wear nearly as much and last a ***lot*** longer. The rubber seal of a push-on connector is forcibly dragged **across** the threads of the valve each and every time the pump head is pushed on and pulled off. There's nothing holding the pump head aligned to prevent the edges of the threads from digging into and tearing the rubber. For a screw-on pump head, the head is aligned by the threads and the rubber gasket never gets dragged *across* the threads under force. That's a big difference.

Answer (score 5):

Threadlocker.

Or bring a valve core wrench with you. For example this high quality metal one from Schwalbe (don’t get their cheap plastic one):
[image]

Some multi tools also have a notch somewhere for presta cores. For example the Topeak Hexus X (though it looks quite flimsy and might fail at just the wrong moment):

[image]

Comment: This one is for Schrader, isn't it? The question is a duplicate anyway.

Comment: @VladimirF: It works for both.

Comment: My mini-pump has a built-in core-tool.

Comment: OK, I thought the other side was a normal valve cap. The problem is, that I had the valve core come off even when I tightened it before screwing the adapter on. A removable core and Presta to Schrader adapters just do not work well together. And threadlockers costs tens of dollars for a bottle while a tube with nonremovable core is much cheaper. With tubeless, nonremovable cores are not an option.

Comment: @VladimirF: I guess you could also use cheap glue instead of “real” threadlocker. I agree that most of the time a tube with non-removable core will cause less issues. But I love the ultralight Schwalbe tubes and they come with removable cores, so no real choice there ;)
I guess there could be some rare cases where your original tube has an irreparable puncture, the *removable* valve on your spare tube breaks and you can combine both for one working tube.

Comment: #3 spoke wrench works great for valve cores, if your multitool has one of those.

Answer (score 4):

Like folks have said, locktite is great (use non permanent!) and it's a good idea to keep extra valve cores and core tool with you, although a couple small allen keys + pliers will do the trick, ask me how I know. But you won't have this problem if you don't over-torque the pump when you attach it. Just tight enough to not leak is what you want, the threads should not be bottomed out. Kid gloves :)